# how to stop cycle that creates a linked list to create one more empty link?

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```
struct data {
  int date;
  int temperature;
  char day[11];
  struct data *next;
}; 
typedef struct data Data;

int from_file_to_list(File *fp, Data **list) {
  Data *p;
  int cnt = 0;
  *list = p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(Data));
  while (fscanf(fp, "%d" "%s" "%d", &(p->date), p->day, &(p->temperature)) == 3) {
    p->next =  malloc(sizeof(Data));
    p = p->next;
    cnt++;
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

I have this function that creates a linked list with the data of a text file and it returns the number of links in the list and it works fine, but it allocates memory for an additional empty link at the end, is there any way to stop that? Because if i would have a function that adds a link in the end there could be problems right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it seems there is a typo

```
int from_file_to_list(File *fp, Data **list) {
                      ^^^^
```

There should be

```
int from_file_to_list(FILE *fp, Data **list) {
                      ^^^^
```

> I have this function that creates a linked list with the data of a
> text file and it returns the number of links in the list and it works
> fine,

You are mistaken. The function has undefined behavior. In this statement

```
int from_file_to_list(File *fp, Data **list) {
  Data *p;
  int cnt = 0;
  *list = p;
  //..
```

you assigned uninitialized pointer `p` to the pointer `*list`. That is after exiting the function the pointer `list` in main will have this indeterminate value.

The function can be defined for example at least the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//... 

size_t from_file_to_list( FILE *fp, Data **list ) 
{
    size_t cnt = 0;

    int date;
    int temperature;
    char day[11];
    
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d" "%s" "%d", &date, day, &temperature ) == 3 && 
            ( *list = malloc( sizeof( Data ) ) ) != NULL ) 
    {
        ( *list )->date = date;
        ( *list )->temperature = temperature;
        strcpy( ( *list )->day, day );
        ( *list )->next = NULL;
        
        list = &( *list )->next;
        ++cnt;
    }
    
    return cnt;
}
```

Or even it will be better to free the list before creating a new list from a file

```
size_t from_file_to_list( FILE *fp, Data **list ) 
{
    while ( *list )
    {
        Data *tmp = *list;
        *list = ( *list )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
    
    size_t cnt = 0;

    int date;
    int temperature;
    char day[11];
    
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d" "%s" "%d", &date, day, &temperature ) == 3 && 
            ( *list = malloc( sizeof( Data ) ) ) != NULL ) 
    {
        ( *list )->date = date;
        ( *list )->temperature = temperature;
        strcpy( ( *list )->day, day );
        ( *list )->next = NULL;
        
        list = &( *list )->next;
        ++cnt;
    }
    
    return cnt;
}
```

If you will write a separate function that clears a list like

```
void clear( Data **list )
{
    while ( *list )
    {
        Data *tmp = *list;
        *list = ( *list )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}
```

then the above function can be written like

```
size_t from_file_to_list( FILE *fp, Data **list ) 
{
    clear ( list );
    
    size_t cnt = 0;

    int date;
    int temperature;
    char day[11];
    
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d" "%s" "%d", &date, day, &temperature ) == 3 && 
            ( *list = malloc( sizeof( Data ) ) ) != NULL ) 
    {
        ( *list )->date = date;
        ( *list )->temperature = temperature;
        strcpy( ( *list )->day, day );
        ( *list )->next = NULL;
        
        list = &( *list )->next;
        ++cnt;
    }
    
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything was really clear, but i don't understand how `list = &( *list )->next;` works

Comment: @Skelemen  You passed the pointer list to the function by reference through a pointer to it did not you? So dereferencing the pointer to pointer like *list within the function you have a direct access to the original pointer list declared in main.  Now after this  statement list = &( *list )->next; the pointer to pointer list  points to the pointer (data member) next of the current node and you can change this pointer the same way as you are changing the original pointer list declared in main through a pointer to it..

Comment: thanks a lot, I've never thought about using that pointer like that, it's so smart.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `*list = p;` *before* `p` is set, so you have UB (undefined behavior).

With that fixed, your code would *not* handle an empty list properly.

Better to read in the values into a `temp` variable and do a `malloc` only if there is a valid data line.

Don't do `malloc` for the *next* record. On the last line of the file, you'd have an *extra* `struct` allocation.

Here's some refactored code. It is annotated. I've compiled it but not tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    int date;
    int temperature;
    char day[11];
    struct data *next;
};
typedef struct data Data;

int
from_file_to_list(FILE *fp, Data **list)
{
    Data temp;
    Data *prev;
    Data *cur;
    int cnt = 0;

    // make the list empty
    *list = NULL;

    prev = NULL;

    // loop on all lines/records in the file
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d" "%s" "%d",
        &temp.date, temp.day, &temp.temperature) == 3) {

        // allocate new record
        cur = malloc(sizeof(*cur));

        // copy in the data we just read
        *cur = temp;

        // append to non-empty list
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = cur;

        // the first record
        else
            *list = cur;

        // remember the previous record
        prev = cur;

        // advance the count of number of records
        cnt++;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```